# Canon AV-1 battery information

Tags: canon, battery, shutter-release

Does anyone know if the [Canon AV-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_AV-1) works without a battery, by works I mean the shutter release, I know the metering system wouldn't work without it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good 'ol mir had some info:

> This camera will not function unless a battery is loaded

http://www.mir.com.my/rb/photography/companies/canon/fdresources/SLRs/av1/htmls/index2.htm

Which I guess makes sense given that it has no manual operation at all, only aperture priority.

Comment: thanks Shizam, now to hunt for some batteries! At least mir also lists batteries I can use instead of mercury ones.